# PHP : Return Same While Value Inside Sub While

Tags: php, while-loop

**Case :**

Hi, Stackoverflow community.

Actually i have looping (while) inside while. That's what i call sub while. I want to return some value from while to sub while same, but it looks like, value can't be read in a sub while.

**Experiment :**

1. Fetch code working normally. All fine, except this $x;
2. There is no other error found, but global $x, can't be printed inside sub while

I try to use global function to declare the while function value. Still, global function can't be read in sub while. The code is barely like this :

```
while (fetch){
$x = value; // multi value, like A, B, C, D, E for example
global $x;
echo $x; // echo print still ok

while (fetch){
echo "<select>". // i use select attribute in this case, it's plus a (.) dot
// so code inside this sub while actually working but $x can't be printed
echo $x; // not print anything
echo "<option" . (($x==$throw[0]) ? 'selected="selected"': '') ."value=".$throw[0].">".$throw[0]."</option>'";
// i use this option attribute, and want $x to be inside the option attribute basically, because it needs to be compared
"</select>";

} // end sub while

} // end while
```

**Desired Output :**

I want value in $x return as is it, like in while loop. Because the multi value inside $x will be compared with $throw[0] which has value shown properly while $x value isn't even shown.

FYI, $x contain several value like for example : A, B, C, D, E.

Do you have any idea why this is happen ? What should i do or modify ?

**Thank You Stackoverflow Community.**

Comment: There should not be a (.) dot after select. echo "<select>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
while (fetch){
$x = value; // multi value, like A, B, C, D, E for example
global $x;
echo $x; // echo print still ok

while (fetch){
echo "<select>".$x; // CHANGED
echo "<option" . (($x==$throw[0]) ? 'selected="selected"': '') ."value=".$throw[0].">".$throw[0]."</option>'";
// i use this option attribute, and want $x to be inside the option attribute basically, because it needs to be compared
"</select>";

} // end sub while

} // end while
```

Comment: in changed code : echo "<select>".$x; // CHANGED. actually it prints $x, but inside echo <option>, it is not, i still wonder why

Comment: Can you show me the output that you desire to achieve?

Comment: [link](https://s31.postimg.org/3xmgalcu3/edit.png) like that, if $x work, it should set default value on select attribute. but turned out, the category isnt selected, that means $x probably can't be read there. i use this code for reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38651772/html-php-set-selected-value-based-on-database-fetched-value)

Comment: @KeshiaAngelina Can you send me the working code with some dummy data for fetch with your desired output it should provide?

Comment: im not sure why but suddenly it's working. selected value won't work because the listed category isnt same like in select category value. thank youuu

Comment: Glad to hear about the success news. Pleasure is all mine Keshia